# CTL Equivalence checking

Tags: ctl

I'm told the following CTL formulas aren't equivalent. However, I can't find a model in which one is true and the other isn't. CTL is a computational temporal logic.

Formula 1:   `AF p OR AF q`
Formula 2:   `AF( p OR q )`

The first says: For all paths starting from the begin state there is a future in which p holds OR for all paths starting from the begin state there is a future in which q holds.

The second: For all paths starting from the begin state there is a future in which p OR q holds.

Answer (score 1):

The model is a little bit tricky. Firstly, one should note that **AF(p OR q)** implies **AF p OR AF q**. So, we are looking for a model in which **AF (p OR q)** is true but **AF p OR AF q** is false.

I am assuming that you are familiar with Kripke model notation described in Logic in Computer Science textbook by M. Huth and M. Ryan (see http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/lics/).

Let M = (S, R, L) be a model with S = {s0, s1, s2} as the set of possible states, R = {(s0,s1), (s0,s2), (s1,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s2)} as the transition relation, and L is a labeling function defined as follows: L(s0) = {} (empty set), L(s1) = {p}, and L(s2) = {q}.

Suppose the starting state is s0. It is clear that **AF (p OR q)** holds at s0. However, **AF p OR AF q** is not satisfied at s0. To prove this, we have to show that *s0 does not satisfy* **AF p** **and** *s0 does not satisfy* **AF q**.

**AF p** is not satisfied at s0 since we can choose the path s0 -> s2 -> s2 -> s2 -> ...

Similarly, **AF q** is not satisfied at s1 since we can choose the path s0 -> s1 -> s1 -> s1 -> ...